# In Java, Why cannot we use generically a common DataStructure like HashMap for all the scenarios?

Tags: java, data-structures

Since, the hardware is becoming very cheap and has very huge memory available these days.Why cannot we use generically a common DataStructure like HashMap for all the scenarios ? If not, is there a short guideline somewhere to know which DataStructure to use in which scenario?.

Comment: This is much too general. Could you provide the scenarios you have questions about?

Comment: You can use a String to store any piece of data, too. To its logical conclusion, you could just as well ask, "why don't we just store everything in byte arrays?"

Comment: This Cannot be a real question.

Comment: @time4tea - I think it's a reasonable question. Some of us may look at it and say, "that's such a basic question" - but everyone has to learn and understand these things sometime. I'd wager most of us spent our first CS/CE semester of Java using Vectors or Hashtables for everything, just because we didn't know/weren't taught any better, or that better things existed and that we should use them.

Comment: Ok. You cannot use a hash map for every single problem in computer science in the same way that you cannot use a pneumatic drill for all drilling in the whole world, even though they are really great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Edit: This answer assumes that you're asking within the context of storing `key -> value` mappings.  If your data doesn't naturally represent mappings, for example a list of Strings, then any kind of `Map` is a poor way to represent it, both in terms of performance and in terms of confusing anyone else who looks at your code.)

Generally speaking, you *can*.  If you're using a map with immutable keys that have decent `hashCode()` implementations (e.g. `String`, any of the auto-boxed primitives), then a HashMap will be perfectly acceptable in general.

However, the different data structures exist for a reason - they all offer difference performance (and occasionally correctness) semantics, so in certain situations you may wish to pick others.

For example, if you want your map entries to be visited in a particular order during iteration (based on the keys), you can use a `TreeMap`.  If you want the iteration order to be based on the order they were inserted, use a `LinkedHashMap`.  If you want good performance under simple concurrent access (with put-if-absent semantics), use a `ConcurrentHashMap`.  If your keys are enums, then an `EnumMap` is hands-down the most efficient implementation.  If you want the keys to be stored as weak refs, use a `WeakHashMap`.  If you want to perform lookups based on the exact object being used (making it safe for mutable keys), use `IdentityHashMap`.

Not to mention that if you know (but are unable to change) that your keys have a poorly-implemented `hashCode()` method, *especially* if it's inconsistent with equals, then `HashMap` may be a poor choice anyway.

And there are many other possible features you may wish your data structure to have that aren't covered able, included (but not limited to):

- Specific iteration order that isn't key-sorted or insertion-order
- Size-boundedness (especially with customisable choice of which entry to kick out)
- Soft/Phantom references for keys
- Lazy initialisation when a `get()` is performed for a key that isn't there

And so on.  This is especially likely if your own domain objects have certain properties that a specific `Map` implementation could take advantage of for faster/cleaner/enhanced performance (which, of course, a generic library implementation could never do).

---

Addressing the "hardware is cheap" statement - this is true, but programmer time and user time is not.  In some cases, the application's critical loop may involve a lot of map lookups, such that speeding up these lookups will have a noticeable effect on performance.  Of course, this usually won't be the case, but if it is, choosing a better performing map for the specific situation (a simple example that comes to mind is using an `EnumMap` where appropriate) will yield performance gains - which can be very important.

Alternatively, some map implementations simply make the surrounding code easier to write, easier to understand, and less likely to harbour bugs.  An example here might be a case of a lazy-initialising map (something like Google Collections' ComputingMap).  While you *can* write some code with lazy-init semantics around a standard `HashMap`, by packing all of this logic inside the map implementation itself it becomes easier to test for correctness - and the client logic is **much** simpler.

So cheap hardware/space doesn't mean that HashMaps are optimal for everything.  In fact, if anything it's a counterargument - HashMaps are reasonably space-efficient compared to the more bespoke alternatives you might adopt.  With lots of cheap space available, it's entirely possible to trade off space against time, storing lots of information in order to speed up lookups.

---

Note that I've interpreted your question as "*why* might you sometimes use other classes of `Map`?" rather than "*which* other `Maps` should you use and when?"  If it's the latter, feel free to rephrase or ask another question that focuses on this more specifically.

Comment: Using the appropriate `Collection` implementation also serves to notify other developers of your intentions. Using a `Set`, for example, immediately tells one that the developer intended its elements to be unique, giving other developers insight into the problem domain.

Comment: Oh, good point Rob.  I thought the question was "why don't we use `HashMap` wherever a `Map` is needed" - but didn't realise it's actually referring to "...wherever a *Collection-like data structure* is needed".

Comment: I think it could be interpreted either way. But your answer is correct in both situations.

Comment: @Andrzej Doyle: IMO, java.util.HashMap is a poor data structure (and close to extinct in our projects). it cannot be predictably iterated, compared to LinkedHashMap, it cannot be used as LRU (also compared to the latter), on top of that it uses bucket linked entries (compared to IdentiryHashMap w/ linear probe algo) which results into a new object creation for each "put'(not a biggie, however HashMap.Entry are on of the top 5-7 in quite a bit of application servers). It's not concurrent, it's not Sorted/NavigableMap (navigble ones are great). So it almost never shines.

Comment: @bestsss: that's a good comment.  I agree that HashMap doesn't have that many bells and whistles (which fundamentally is the conclusion of my answer).  However, what it *does* do well, is *pretty fast* key-based lookups objects in general (assuming decent hashcodes).  If you just want the basic functionality of a `java.util.Map`, without LRU/concurrent/other extras, then IMO the HashMap makes a good general time/space tradeoff.  (And NavigableMaps *are* good if you need navigability, but irrelevant if you're just calling `put()` and `get()`.)

Comment: @Andrzej Doyle, with current architecture designs (CPU/memory cache) the linked buckets make HashMap just poor, why? Even w/ near perfect hash code distribution you are looking at: a new object allocation on put (allocations are relatively more expensive than GC) and then on get you have a practical cache-miss due to the entry indirection, being allocated totally not anywhere near the Object[] where it resides. A linear-probe hashmap will yeild significantly better performance. With some collisions HashMap deals even poorer due to iterating through Linked structure to find the proper entry.

Answer (score 2):

Because Hashmap is not ordered, because a stable hashcode is sometimes hard to define... Well for many reasons there are other structures. A good introduction is the Java Collections tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html

Answer (score 2):

To partially answer the first part of your question, note that there are important differences between the collection classes. Choosing one of them as the "default" would be tricky.

A HashMap is a Map, which is not always what you want - sometimes a List, or a Stack is most appropriate.

To answer the second part of your question, believe it or not but one of the best things I ever did was read the javadoc for the Collections package; each class has notes that I found really useful. For example, http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html gives an overview, and then choose any implementation like a Stack to find out more about it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

While a HashMap is useful in many situations, and yes, hardware is becoming very cheap, there are situations where information should be kept sequentially or at least in some type of order.  Also, in the event of a data structure that a user may want to reorder (Say a student directory, it could be ordered by last name, first name, birthday, GPA, etc.) a HashMap may not be the easiest to work with.  A HashMap could still be used in any situation that I can think of, but it could be easier, and definitely more computationally efficient to use a different structure in many situations.

Here's some reading:
http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14639

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPAlgorithms.fm.html (CTRL + F "8.4")